# Should I use /etc/skel or /etc/profile.d for a Custom Live CD?

Tags: live-usb, home-directory

I've been making a [Custom Live CD from Scratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch), and I want my home directory to be preserved for live use.

I've run across /etc/skel, which looks promising, but seems to be only for adding users- not much docs on using it for live booting.

I've also seen some scanty docs on /etc/profile.d, but it seems to be more about executing scripts on boot than anything else.

How can I make it so that when a user boots my ISO live, they find all the config files and customizations I've made, along with the home directory that I've added content to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct folder is `/etc/skel`

Anything in that folder will be copied on boot to the live user home folder.

If making a custom Live CD, you can simply use `cp -r /home/yourusername/. /etc/skel/`

Adding the `.` after the `yourusername/` ensures that `.hidden` folders are copied too.