# Customize Ubuntu ISO file to boot automatically from RAM

Tags: boot, system-installation

In Ubuntu, one can boot a live USB fully to ram using `toram` option.
[adding toram option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8XjX.png)

However this procedure is GUI based. Is there anyway to just write down the `toram` option to the ISO file so that the bootable USB directly boots from RAM?

The GUI based way to boot Ubuntu from RAM is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829917/can-i-boot-a-live-usb-fully-to-ram-allowing-me-to-remove-the-disk).

Edit: All of the mentioned and proposed idea works. Although, I accepted one solution, One can try any of those methods according to their necessity.

Comment: Hi..this question may have the answer as one of the point in the below link..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1175819/739431 point No.5 in the answer..

Comment: If you create a persistent live USB boot drive with the tool [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), you will find an option, that lets you boot 'live-only to RAM'. You can easily edit the `grub.cfg` file (in partition #3 of the USB boot drive) to move this menuentry to the top (or even remove the other menuentries).

Comment: If you are booting an ISO file,you are likely using GRUB2. You can add `toram` to the linux line of grub.cfg. right after quiet splash or at the end, one space after -- will work. I will add a proper answer as soon as I have time.

Comment: In the end I want to install the custom device on multiple machines and automatically boot from ram. 
@sudodus  I know what is persistent live USB. But the next part , I did not get. But I think that is machine dependent, every time I have to go through the same procedure? 
@C.S.Cameron so you are suggesting that I can edit the gurb add the `toram` option ? IS the machine dependent too ? for every new machine I have to go through the same procedure  ?

Comment: @Tokai, You can create one persistent live drive in a USB pendrive (with or without edits to `grub.cfg`), and then you can clone it to other USB pendrives or internal drives for the machines that you want to boot `toram`.

Comment: @Tokai, If C.S.Cameron has the time, and you want it, he might write a step-wise description of a 'grub-n-iso' or 'isoboot' method to get what you want, something like [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/isoboot) but focusing on `toram`.

Comment: @sudodus I got the C.S. Cameron's idea. It seems the solution link provided by UnKnown and C.S. Cameron and you , point almost in same direction. Cubic provides a gui in where a menuentry  provided by Cameron has to be pasted. Which edits the grub.cfg file you mentioned. I just read a bit and now understand better :) I am trying out all the the ideas for learning. Thanks for your kind notes. I will update the answer after I finish playing with these methods.

Comment: Good luck @Tokai :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Booting ISO file `toram`

If you are booting an ISO file,you are likely using GRUB2. You can add `toram` to the linux line of grub.cfg. right after quiet splash or at the end, one space after --

**Boot ISO menuentry may look like:**

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 20.04 ISO" {
    rmmod tpm
    set root=(hd0,1)
    set isofile="/isos/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile persistent persistent-path=/ub2004-1/ fsck.mode=skip quiet splash toram -- 
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

**More on booting ISO files** using a simple BIOS/UEFI template image here: [BIOS/UEFI Template Image for Booting ISO Files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files)

Comment: @Tokai, This works provided that the file system is read/write :-) This is why I suggested a persistent live drive by mkusb, or a 'grub-n-iso' alias 'isoboot' method. (In standard (cloned directly from the iso file) USB boot drives, there is a iso9660 file system which is read-only.)

Comment: @Tokai: I should mention that sudodus has been working on a Template image for booting ISO files in BIOS and in UEFI modes. It can be installed to a USB from Windows using Rufus or Etcher. It can be installed in Linux using mkusb and Disks. once flashed just add an ISO, or a few, and update grub.cfg if necessary. See: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=100&p=13979560#post13979560 for more details.