# BIOS/UEFI Template Image for Booting ISO Files

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-installation, persistence

The creator of **mkusb** has released an Template Image for creating  BIOS/UEFI boot partitions on a USB.

How can I use this image to boot ISO files from a USB?

Comment: There are instructions at this link to an Ubuntu help page: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/isoboot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/isoboot). You are welcome to add more use cases and more user friendly instructions here :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Booting ISO Files with **mkusb** BIOS/UEFI GRUB Template Image

There are a few pre-built programs available for multibooting Linux systems:
MultiBootUSB, Ventoy and YUMI.
The inner workings of these tools is not very transparent.

Now it is easy to build an ISO booting USB that works in BIOS and ISO mode from scratch.

There are several versions of the mkusb BIOS/UEFI GRUB template.

https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios.img.xz
For use in Windows 10 and in Linux.

https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/mkusb_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios_fat32_4GB_use-in-wins.img.xz
For use in Windows 7 thru 10, it has a 4GB FAT32 No 1 partition that is accessible in older versions of Windows or IOS.

MD5SUM's can be found here: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/grub-boot-templates-for-uefi-n-bios.md5.

**Basic ISO Booter** (Min 4GB USB)

- Flash `mkusb_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios_fat32_4GB_use-in-wins.img` to a USB using Rufus, Etcher, Gnome-Disks, mkusb or etc. (Use 7zip to extract from xz if necessary).
- Copy the ISO file for any flavor of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) or Linux Mint* to the USB.
- Rename the ISO file to `ubuntu.iso`.
- Boot the USB and confirm that everything works.

Linux Mint, Elementary OS and some flavors of Ubuntu may require `initrd.lz` rather than `initrd` in grub.cfg.

**Basic ISO Booter with Persistent Partition Alt1** (Min 4GB USB)
Only one persistent partition is allowed per Computer.

- Create Basic ISO Booter above.
- Boot USB, open GParted and format empty space to the right of the boot partitions as ext4, label it `casper-rw`.

**Basic ISO Booter with Persistent Partition Alt2** (Min 4GB USB)

- Create Basic ISO Booter above.
- Boot the USB, at the boot menu select live-only option  and press `e` to edit.
- Use the arrow keys to get to the end of the linux line, (one space after the word `nopersistent`). and type `toram` then press F10 to boot.
- In Terminal type `sudo umount -lrf /isodevice` to unmount the USB.
- Open GParted. Move EFI boot partition 1MB from right side. Move BIOS boot partition next to it. click apply, Adjust Partition No1 size as required.
- Create a new ext4 partition in the unused space, label it `casper-rw`
- A persistent partition labeled home-rw can also be created, It is similar to a /home partition in a Full install.
- Boot the USB using the persistent menuentry option.

**Named ISO Files**

- Boot the USB and edit `grub.cfg` using

  ```
  sudo gedit -H /media/ubuntu/usbboot/boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```

  Add proper ISO names, (and path), as shown below. Note: Using `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to edit `grub.cfg` does not work with ISO files.

  ```
  menuentry "ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso live-only" {
     set isofile="/ubuntu-20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
     loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash maybe-ubiquity nopersistent
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
  ```

**ISO Multi-Booter** (Min 8GB USB)

- Boot `toram` and move boot partitions as above using GParted.
- Resize FAT32 partition to fill empty space.
- Copy preferred Ubuntu flavors (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) ISO's to USB.
- Edit grub.cfg providing a uniquely named menuentry for each ISO.

**ISO Multi-Booter with Multi-Persistence** (16GB+ USB)

- Create multi-booter as above.
- Add a uniquely named folder to a FAT32 partition for each ISO file requiring persistence if not already there.
- Add a persistence file labeled `writable` to each folder.
- Add a persistence file labeled `home-rw` to each folder as desired.*
- Edit `linux` line of each `persistent` menuentry adding `persistent-path=foldername`

Example: `linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash fsck.mode=skip persistent persistent-path=ubuntu-20.04.1`

**To create persistence file:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F casper-rw
```

- (Replace 512 with the "size in MB" you require, max 4000)
- For Ubuntu 20.04 and later replace `casper-rw` with `writable`
- For a `home-rw` partition replace `casper-rw` with `home-rw`

**Additional Tweaks**

- Booting to RAM: Add `toram` at the end of the grub.cfg menuentry linux line.
- Eliminating Disk Check: Add `fsck.mode=skip` at the end of the grub.cfg `live-only` menuentry linux line.
- Eliminating Try/Install screen: Remove `maybe-ubiquity` from the grub.cfg `live-only` menuentry linux line.
- Safe Graphics Mode: Add `nomodeset` at the end of the grub.cfg menuentry linux line.
- To watch boot progress remove `quiet splash` from the menuentry linux line.
- Personalize a persistent ISO. Go to settings/Users and add a New User and a password. You can make new users for each persistent ISO.
- Additional menuentries see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples
- When booted from the USB, data copied to the disk is located in the isodevice folder.

- There seems to be some problem with home-rw files, persistent-paths and Ubuntu 20.04 right now.

**These templates require editing to work with other Linux distros**

- Some other Linux distros have much in common with Ubuntu, but the  internal boot structure is usually different from standard Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours, so it would be necessary to tweak the grub configuration (in the menuentries of `grub.cfg`).
- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Linux_distros_where_mkusb_works) can create live-only as well as persistent live drives from several non-Ubuntu ISO files, for example Debian Live and Linux Mint.

**Additional Menuentries for some popular Linux distro's:**

**Debian Live**

```
menuentry "debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-gnome" {
    set isofile="/debian-live-10.5.0/debian-live-10.5.0-amd64-gnome.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz-4.19.0-10-amd64 boot=live findiso=$isofile persistence persistence-path=debian-live-10.5.0
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img-4.19.0-10-amd64
}
```

**To create persistence file:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=persistence bs=1M count=512
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F persistence
```

then mount it

```
mkdir perst
sudo mount persistence perst
```

Create a persistence.conf file

```
echo / union >persistence.conf
echo >>persistence.conf
```

Move it to the `perst` directory.

And unmount:

```
sudo umount perst
```

**To create persistence partition:**

Create an ext4 partition, label it `persistence` and drop a persistence.conf file into it.

Comment: @sudodus: Thank you for the new edit. I think I will have Debian working soon, unfortunately I downloaded the Installer version rather than the Live version. To get the installer version working I edited grub.cfg, changing `/casper/vmlinuz` to `/install.amd/vmlinuz` and `/casper/initrd` to `/install.amd/initrd.gz`. I have not had a chance to play with persistence yet. I will leave the edits until I have confirmed the fix on Debian Live.

Comment: @sudodus: I got a copy of Debian Live. The grub.cfg menuentry needs a few mods to boot. `casper` needs to be changed to `live` in three places and findiso=$isofile needs to be added to the `linux` line. Both `vmlinuz` and `iinitrd.img` should be followed by `-4.19.0-10-amd64` I think it works better without `splash`. Persistent becomes persistence and `fsck.mode=skip` is not required. I think casper-rw/writable is called persistence.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about that. Additionally I think you need a small file in the partition for persistence. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy#Persistence_with_Debian_10_live).

Comment: @sudodus: Linux Mint worked out of the box, but had to change `initrd` to `initrd.lz`. Lubuntu 16.04 also uses `initrd.lz`. `casper-rw` still works for the persistence file, `writable` doesn't.

Comment: That's great :-) With these examples in your answer it will also help people, who might want to extend the method to other iso files (because it indicates what might be necessary to tweak).

Comment: Now there is also `mkusb_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios_fat32_4GB_use-in-wins_2020-09-07.img.xz` which I think is better than the previous 'wins' files. Please check that it works for you and let me know the result. See also [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447379&p=13985029#post13985029). You may suggest that I add another link or two to the end of that post in the Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: @sudodus: That is number three on tomorrows to do list. I will give it a few runs and then update this answer. Your new Ubuntu full install image files are numbers one and two.