# how to create an ubuntu usb installer from an .iso file

Tags: system-installation, usb, iso

I've tried with the startup disk creator app but without success.
What terminal program could I use? its man pages work well?

thanks in advance!

Comment: 0. Please edit your original question to describe in a detailed way what is going wrong; 1. In which version of Ubuntu are you using the Startup Disk Creator? It is a robust cloning tool in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions, but a buggy tool in earlier versions; 2. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? You can tell us the name of the iso file -- When we know this, it will be possible to give more detailed advice (otherwise we can only guess what is the problem).

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782