# Why can Ubuntu see one of my Windows drives, but not the other?

Tags: gparted

I have Windows laptop and want to use Ubuntu to back it up when none of the Windows files are open, then use it for emergency re-install.

My drives look like this:

[image]

The top one is an internal SATA hard drive, the second is an internal SSD drive and the lower is an external drive with Ubuntu installed.

When I boot into Ubuntu and run Gparted, it sees the Linux drive (obliviously), and the SATA drive, but not the SSD with the Windows partition.

What am I doing wrongly, and do you need any more info to help you to help me?

Comment: It looks like an Ubuntu live installer which is just over 2GB and rest of drive is not used. Better to use a smaller drive for the live installer. Have you checked if Windows fast start up is off? Note that Windows udpates turn it back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Please accept my apologies for the delay in replying. Yes, that did the trick. Please either post it as an answer, which I will accept, or close it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use small drives as Ubuntu live installer. Most tools totally erase drive and then only use about 2.5GB depending on flavor or version.

It looks like an Ubuntu live installer  and rest of drive is not used. Better to use a smaller drive for the live installer. Have you checked if Windows fast start up is off? Note that Windows udpates turn it back on.

If Windows fast start up is an issue. See these for details on turning it off. Note that Windows updates turn fast start up back on, so if issues in future double check setting.

[Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions)

[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

There are some more advanced ways to boot installer ISO directly from grub using its loopmount. I typically like to have a small install on every drive and then can just add ISOs Ubuntu & other repair ISO and directly boot with grub.  then larger flash drive or other external drive is not dedicated to just an install ISO of 2+GB.

ISO boot & link to examples

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

more examples

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c

[BIOS/UEFI Template Image for Booting ISO Files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files)

Comment: An excellent and detailed answer, which should help others who read this question in future