# GRUB: boot an ISO from a different partition

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

Please Note: I read all posts in here, about booting ISO from partition using GRUB2
and based on that, I have tried the following, which is not worknig:

I have these partitions and I want to boot an ISO from `/dev/sda5` -- should be `(hda0,5)` in
GRUB terms.

```
root@myhost:/home/vyom# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    30G  0 disk 
`-sda1   8:1    0   243M  0 part [SWAP]
`-sda2   8:2    0  11.2G  0 part /
`-sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
`-sda5   8:5    0   9.3G  0 part /mypart5    <<<
`-sda6   8:6    0   9.3G  0 part /mypart6
root@myhost:/home/vyom# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="79813f4a-85da-4c81-a044-097922b30648" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="68923f34-385e-4740-b8af-4502aa3dd847" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="ef7ca072-bfc9-457b-8a9e-b923fa0d3fe7" TYPE="ext4"   <<<
/dev/sda6: UUID="d8bd9333-dc41-47b3-8a42-f6c308a6f047" TYPE="ext4"
```

I tried using UUID with `--fs-uuid` and `fromiso=` - didn't work:

```
menuentry 'UbuntuBionicVSCustom4' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
   set isofile="/mypart5/ubuntu-18.04-3f8806d-test2.iso" 
   insmod ext2
   insmod loopback
   insmod iso9660
   loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ef7ca072-bfc9-457b-8a9e-b923fa0d3fe7
   linux (loop)/install/vmlinuz boot=install fromiso=/dev/sda5/$isofile noprompt noeject
   initrd (loop)/install/initrd.gz
}
```

I tried `--file` option to `search` - that too didnt work:

```
menuentry 'UbuntuBionicVSCustom3' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
   set isofile="/mypart5/versa-flexvnf-3f8806d-21.2.1-B-S.iso"
   insmod ext2
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod lvm
   insmod loopback
   insmod iso9660
   search --file --no-floppy --set=root "${isofile}"
   loopback loop "(${root})${isofile}"
   linux (loop)/install/vmlinuz boot=install findiso="${isofile}" noprompt noeject
   initrd (loop)/install/initrd.gz
}
```

The ISO file is actually at: `/mypart5/ubuntu-18.04-3f8806d-test2.iso`

So, should I do:

```
   set isofile="/mypart5/ubuntu-18.04-3f8806d-test2.iso"
```

OR, just:

```
   set isofile="ubuntu-18.04-3f8806d-test2.iso"
```

So that, next I can do:

```
   loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
```

also, I am confused with the kernel command line options, should I use:

```
     fromiso=/dev/sda5/$isofile
```

OR

```
     findiso="${isofile}"
```

OR

```
     iso-scan/filename=${isofile}
```

OR

```
     isoloop=/${isofile}
```

I am not able to get GRUB to actually pick the file from the partition /dev/sda5
mounted on `/mypart5`. I get `"error: no such device"`  or `unknown filesystem` . Please help me what I am missing here!

Comment: More info on booting ISO files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782

Comment: Try adding a slash: set isofile="/ubuntu-18.04-3f8806d-test2.iso"

Comment: More examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples  If you have created a custom ISO, best to test path & boot stanza with a known working ISO. Then you know detals are correct and whether issue is path, boot stanza, or ISO itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
menuentry 'UbuntuBionicVSCustom3' {
  set root='hd0,5'
  set isofile=/ubuntu-18.04-3f8806d-test2.iso
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/install/vmlinuz boot=install iso-scan/filename="${isofile}" noprompt noeject
  initrd (loop)/install/initrd.gz
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP is using msdos partition tables, not gpt. The ISO should boot fine just using (hd0,5), no gpt, msdos required.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Indeed, I just wanted to highlight the diference between the two partition tables, for future readers.

Comment: Adding gpt or msdos just makes things more complicated and is not required.

Comment: Oh, ok, what happens is that some time ago I couldn't boot an ISO if *gpt* was not specified, but I may be misremembering. I'll update the answer removing that part.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity you probably meant just `/iso-file` when you wrote `/path/to/iso`. I had to just remove the mount directory and use like: `set isofile="/the-iso-file` and `loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile`. Now that ISO boots, its getting stuck at loading CD-ROM! (separate issue though). Thanks. Can I edit your answer to what worked for me ?

Comment: @vyom when you `set root='hd0,5'`, you don't need then to add it to the `loopback`. Every path in the configuration  will assume the root as `'hd0,5'`, meaning `/` *is* `hd0,5`. `/path/to/the/iso` represents any path in your 5th partition where you put the image. For example, you can place it under a directory called `isos`. The path then would be `/isos/$isofile` (translated = `(hd0,5)/isos/theiso.iso`).

Comment: @vyom Updated the answer according to your needs I hope, let me know of any problem.

Comment: @vyom I said *-"Every path in the configuration will assume the root as 'hd0,5'"-*, but it is *some* paths, depending on the config keyword.