# Make a full bootable usb stick with Gnome disk utility

Tags: grub2, live-usb, iso, gnome-disk-utility

I want to make a usb stick bootable with multiple iso files. How can I do it via Gnome disk utility? How can I config the usb for showing grub2 before starting any of ISOs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Make a Full Bootable USB Stick with Gnome-Disk Utility

To create a bootable Live Linux USB using Gnome-Disks:

- Open Disks.
- Plug in Target drive.
- Select Target drive in left hand column.
- Select the three lines or dots on the upper right of the window.
- Click **Restore Disk Image**.
- Select the Linux ISO as **Image to Restore**.
- Follow the instructions.

If your intentions are to make a **Full Install** bootable USB:

- Click **Restore Disk Image**.
- Select an image file of a Linux system as **Image to Restore**. You can find an image of Ubuntu 20.04 at: [Easy Full Install USB that Boots both BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi)

Both methods should start with a grub menu when booting in UEFI mode. or with BIOS or UEFI in 20.10 and later.

Comment: Thank you! I want to have more than 1 ISO files in the USB but when I click "Restore Disk Image", it replaces with the ISO I add before instead of adding.

Comment: The method I prefer to boot multiple ISO's on a drive is shown here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files. This can also be done by creating  your own boot partitions as shown as part of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step (See Note 1). This procedure can be a little confusing.

Comment: More on booting ISO's see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files. You can make your own boot partitions and install GRUB as in the above link if you do not want to use an image.

Comment: Tnak you for the links