# Problem with Startup disk creator

Tags: 20.04

I'm not able to select an iso file in a startup disk creator. whenever I choose a file it does not show up in the option and that's why not able to boot a  USB drive.

Comment: Have you verified the checksums of the `.iso` files? What does `file *.iso` tell you?

Comment: Try using **Gnome-Disks** to make your Live USB, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335903/make-a-full-bootable-usb-stick-with-gnome-disk-utility/1335942#1335942 If that does not work download the Ubuntu ISO again.