# Lubuntu installed image for USB

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

I wanted to do a full install of Lubuntu on a USB stick but after reading about the risk of messing up the internal drive, found the following link but it is for Ubuntu. It looks like a less risky way to get a full install onto an external drive.

Is there a similar image like this for Lubuntu that I can download? Thanks in advance.

[Easy Full Install USB that Boots both BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi)

Comment: Do you need both UEFI & BIOS? If system is old & BIOS, you just need to use Something Else install option and be sure to install boot loader to external drive. If UEFI, the choice of where to install grub does not work with Ubiquity installer. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Several workarounds in bug report. You can disconnect internal drive, temporarily remove ESP flag from internal drive, or mount correct ESP during install manually.  You need to partition in advance. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: @oldfred, Thanks for the response. Yes, because I want to be able to use this external drive or USB on any computer around school or at friends' place with my favourite applications always available.

Comment: That Image was built by sudodus, the creator of mkusb. I don't think he has built one for Lubuntu 20.04, but I will check. Sudodus can be PM'd over at Ubuntu Forums. The method that was used to make the image is shown on this page : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step. See the link to K1tty if you need more clarification.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron , Thanks. I hope that in future more distros would provide sudodus-type images.

Comment: There is another method that can be used for BIOS/UEFI installs of other Ubuntu flavours, give me a little time and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, Thanks.

Comment: @Community, I'm new and not confident of installing Lubuntu onto a USB without messing up my PC. I'm asking to see if an installed image of Lubuntu similar to the Ubuntu one provided by sudodus in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi  is available.

Comment: @groot I see this sudodus image for Lubuntu, but it is for 18.04.1: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64-persistent-n-installed_15GB.img.xz - It is 1.9GB to download. If you unplug your HDD when installing, you should be safe with the method below.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks. If I download the 18.04.1 and flash it to a USB, can  I run the "Software Update" app to update it to 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

### BIOS/UEFI Boot Partitions for Full Install Ubuntu and Flavours

Sudodus provides a BIOS/UEFI GRUB Template Image that can be used for Full installs as well as booting ISO files

See [BIOS/UEFI Template Image for Booting ISO Files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files) for some background.

Here is how to use it for Full installs:

- Download the image: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios.img.xz
- Flash dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios.img to a USB using Rufus, Etcher, Gnome-Disks, mkusb or etc. (Use 7zip to extract from xz if necessary).
- Boot a Live USB of the Ubuntu flavour you want to install, in this case Lubuntu.
- Proceed with installation and choose the **Something else** option.
- Under **Device for boot loader installation** select the target USB drive.
- Select the USB free space and click +, select use as Ext4, select format this partition, and Mount point = "/" then OK. (Leave a bit of space to the right if you want a Data partition).
- If asked to Write previous changes... click Continue.
- Confirm the only partition to be formatted is the one just created. If asked, click continue.
- Select your location. click "Continue"
- Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select if you want to log in automatically or require a password.
- Click "Continue".
- Wait until install is complete.
- Copy /boot/grub/grub.cfg from sdx3 to overwrite /boot/grub/grub.cfg on sdx2.
- You can add a new FAT32 or NTFS partition for data if you wish.