# Persistent storage: How do I set it up using Ubuntu Live 22.04 LTS?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I've just downloaded the latest version of Ubuntun for Desktop, version 22.04 LTS.

At the moment, I don't want to install it onto my hard disk drive. I wish to try it first.

Does Ubuntu Live 22.04 LTS support the creation of persistent storage? If yes, can you show me how to do it under Debian please? Thanks.

Comment: See https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/rufus-creating-persistent-storage-live.html or https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ or https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/create-persistent-storage-live-usb-with.html

Comment: You write the ISO to your installation media to use the *persistence* instead of being a simple *live* RO image.  Myself I use `mkusb` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb  (*and use it in both Ubuntu & off-topic Debian*)

Comment: @guiverc `You write the ISO to your installation media to use the persistence instead of being a simple live RO image.` I know that already. But how do you do it under Debian? By the way, `mkusb` isn't available in Debian.

Comment: `mkusb` isn't available in Ubuntu repositories either.. It's a 3rd party package for both Ubuntu & Debian.  Debian isn't on-topic on this site though; but everything I'd need to install it (*and likely how I installed it on my Debian systems; including bookworm, bullseye*...) was found on the wiki link I've already provided.

Comment: There is something about running Debian Persistent on a Ubuntu Multi-Boot USB here, toward the bottom: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269476/43926