# Can't get to the GNU GRUB after creating multi boot flash drive. Help?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, flash

I recently created a multi boot usb drive but can't get to the windows boot manager window. It automatically opens to windows 10 instead of giving me the option of which os to run. I shut off the computer and reinserted the flash and went through the same ubuntu installation process, only for it to tell me I already have both Windows 10 and ubuntu downloaded on this system. There's just simply no way to access either this latest 22.04 or the previous 16.04 that I also included on the flash. There should be a grub menu that pops up immediately upon starting the computer, but nada. Instead it takes me to the Windows 10 starting point. Anyone run into this problem that would be able to share a solution? THANKS.

Comment: I have multiple flash drives with various ISO, used to be BIOS, but now most are UEFI.  Now large ones have a full install & various repair ISO. Is your system UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you must have an ESP on any external drive if you want to directly boot it. UEFI boots from ESP, using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. And you also must have /EFI/ubuntu folder as Ubuntu's version of bootx64.efi is hard coded to find other files in the ubuntu folder. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289225

Comment: What method did you use to make the Multi Boot flash drive, Ventoy, YUMI, Full Install or ISO booter or other?

Comment: I downloaded the ubuntu 22.04 iso directly from ubuntu website while using 16.04, restarted and went into windows 10, I used rufus to create the bootable flash. I still have it engaged which is how I'm using ubuntu right now. Upon restarting the computer with the flash inserted, eventually you get to a point where you can either re-install ubuntu or use the test version (which I'm on right now),