# Customized ubuntu desktop that can boot to RAM

Tags: partitioning, grub2, 20.04, isolinux, boot-to-ram

I'm working on a project to customize an ubuntu desktop iso to add/remove packages and eventually have it boot to RAM. Here is my overall idea.

- Create a custom OS that can be flashed into a USB and used to boot a target machine
- Once booted, run a script that creates a persistent partition in my hard disk and copy the iso to the partition
- Every single boot after running the script, shall use the image in the partition and boot to RAM.
- While booting, installation should happen automatically.

**Background**

I was able to achieve the above mentioned functionality in Debian stretch and I thought it will be fairly straightforward and tried to reuse the scripts for Ubuntu. No surprise, I was wrong. Then I started to reach out online. Learnt and tried the following steps.

- Used Cubic after reading this post - [Create an unattended ubuntu 18.04 live cd that run on demo (try ubuntu) environment with premade various steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175819/create-an-unattended-ubuntu-18-04-live-cd-that-run-on-demo-try-ubuntu-environm). Unable to boot from RAM. Also tried `toram` option - Not working
- For automatic installation, I referred to [this git repo](https://github.com/hiragashi/ubuntu-unattended-install) and I was able to accomplish it by modifying preseed and isolinux/txt.cfg file.
- Also read through these tutorials:

  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization - I believe this is similar to what Cubic is doing under the hood. Not much useful apart from learning the inner workings.
  - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM - Super out of date and the author even mentions some steps that are not clean.

**What I'm looking for?**

- I understood how to customize Ubuntu by unpacking it, changing root and installing packages - I'm capable of accomplishing this.
- Run through installation unattended by modifying preseed file - No issues
- During every boot, the OS present in the a hard disk persistent partition must be copied to RAM - Tried a lot, no avail. Also, this may be related to grub.cfg and isolinux/txt.cfg. Not sure.

I'm sure, I'm doing something blatantly wrong. Please forgive me if I come across as a dumb person. I may not be using jargons appropriately. Also, I can improve this question and give more information based on what you are asking. I had to start somewhere! Thank you

**Edits**

Based on the comments, I tried the following. Please note, I'm using cubic.

- Boot options directory looks like the following:

[image]

- Unedited boot/grub/grub.cfg looks like the following:

[image]

- My modification:

[image]

- Unmodified isolinux/txt.cfg looks like the following and **I erased all contents inside**:

[image]

- Unfortunately, this was my output:

[image]

I'm super confused as to what files to modify. I'm not able to understand when the isolinux is used and when grub.cfg is used. Do I have to modify both the same way ? Can someone help me out on this please ?

Comment: Just boot the iso stored on SSD from grub.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? Thanks

Comment: I'm on my phone but you can google it.

Comment: Everything you could want to know about booting an ISO from GRUB2: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files

Comment: I had experience with building custom Ubuntu ISO's for 16.04 version (the ones released in 2016) I used that ISO for 4 years. I bought a new computer. When it was time for building a new ISO for myself, I've encountered several problems with using Ubuntu again (including repositories problems, which should be an essential part of it) In my opinion, Ubuntu-based distros are not up to par in terms of care anymore. I would recommend using MX Linux because it's based off Debian 10 Buster. Now I understand why people compliment Debian so much. Can't go wrong with Debian really.