# How do I add toRam option to the starting screen with Cubic?

Tags: live-usb, iso, custom-installer

How do I modify the Ubuntu ISO with cubic so that I can add the toRam option to the screen where I get the try/install options?

Comment: Point 5 in this post may help. https://askubuntu.com/a/1176116/739431

Comment: @UnKNOWn yep, this should do it. Tnx.